# SNAPSHOT Artifacts not visible in eclipse after mvn install

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, repository, snapshot

1. from proj-a folder: run mvn install proj-a
2. from proj-b folder: (proj-b depends on proj-a) run mvn clean eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
3. refresh proj-b in eclipse.

jars that proj-a depends on are in the proj-b classpath, but proj-a-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is missing. proj-a-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is in the local repository.

1. run mvn deploy for proj-a
2. delete proj-a folder from local repository
3. run mvn eclipse:eclipse from proj-b folder - all jars are visible.

what can cause this problem? all artifacts should be available right after install operation. mvn does not complains about nothing....

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me handling maven projects in eclipse becomes easier using [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/). After you have installed the plugin, right click on your project > `Maven > Enable Dependency Management` so that it becomes a maven eclipse project. Then, given you have run your `mvn install` and you can see your SNAPSHOT jar in your local repository, right click on your maven project > `Maven > Update Snapshots` or in general `Maven > Update Dependencies`.